# Using Java to call Linux terminal: How to flush the output?

Tags: java, linux, terminal, flush

1) I'm using Java to call Linux terminal to run foo.exe and save the output in a file:

```
    String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "foo >haha.file"};
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

2) The problem is when I plan to read haha.file later in the code, it hasn't been written yet:

```
File f=new File("haha.file"); // return true
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("haha.file"));
reader=in.readLine();
System.out.println(reader);//return null
```

3) Only after the program is done will the haha.file be written. I only know how to flush "Writers" but don't know how to flush sth. like this.
How can I force java to write the file in the terminal?

Thanks in advance
E.E.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the asynchronous nature of [Runtime.exec](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29).  `foo` is being executed in a seperate process.  You need to call [Process.waitFor()](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) to insure the file has been written.

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "foo >haha.file"};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
// ....
if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
    File f=new File("haha.file");
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("haha.file"));
    reader=in.readLine();
    System.out.println(reader);
} else {
    //process did not terminate normally
}
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach.  There are nasties lurking with the stdout/stderr stream when using exec().  You really need to ASYNCHRONOUSLY consume the output/error streams while waitFor() is blocking otherwise it may never return because the stdout/err buffers fill up and block the forked processes.  Checkout apache commons-exec for a lib that solves this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either wait for the completion of the process:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
int result = p.waitFor();
```

Or use the p.getInputStream() to read directly from the standard output of the process.